# EDIT: Python how to create bins with equal amount of data and plot them?

Tags: python

I got 6056 volume & price data, and I want to create 20 bins(volume) with equal amount of data in each bin, find the average volume and price within each bin and plot a graph of volume(x-axis) against price(y-axis)

I am trying to modify my code to change the interval so that it can contain the same number of data points

the intervals don't need to be equally spaced. I want to have the same number of data in each interval and determine the range of each interval, then find the average value of the data within each interval and plot it

[image]

my current code is:

```
dat = df['Volume_norm']

def discretize(data, bins):
    split = np.array_split(np.sort(data), bins)
    cutoffs = [x[-1] for x in split]
    cutoffs = cutoffs[:-1]
    discrete = np.digitize(data, cutoffs, right=True)
    return discrete, cutoffs

discrete_dat, cutoff = discretize(dat, 50)

df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : TradeN['Volume_norm'], 'Y' : TradeN['dMidP']})  #we build a dataframe from the data
data_cut = pd.cut(dat,Cutoff)            #we cut the data following the bins               #we cut the data following the bins     
grp = df.groupby(by = data_cut)        #we group the data by the cut
ret = grp.aggregate(np.mean)
```

however, when I count the data, this returns me:

```
Counter({Interval(0.376, 0.46400000000000002, closed='right'): 2065,
         Interval(0.83899999999999997, 0.92800000000000005, closed='right'): 563,
         Interval(0.046399999999999997, 0.0557, closed='right'): 63,
         Interval(0.56100000000000005, 0.67200000000000004, closed='right'): 121,
         Interval(0.46400000000000002, 0.51000000000000001, closed='right'): 145,
         Interval(0.11600000000000001, 0.14399999999999999, closed='right'): 105,
         Interval(0.013899999999999999, 0.023199999999999998, closed='right'): 144,
         Interval(0.14399999999999999, 0.186, closed='right'): 119,
         Interval(0.186, 0.23200000000000001, closed='right'): 134,
```

which means the number of data in each range is still different

Comment: You cannot satisfy both constraint of bins of equal interval, and bins containing the same number of data points in the general case. - please clarify your question by stating precisely what you want, or post your data set.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I didnt want to create bins of equal interval, so I am trying to modify my code to change the interval so that it can contain the same number of data points

Comment: What you really want is still unclear.

Comment: the intervals don't need to be equally spaced. I want to have the same number of data in each interval and determine the range of each interval, then find the average value of the data within each interval and plot it

Comment: Great, I'll put back my answer.

Comment: You must amend your question to reflect the precisions you put in the comments.

Comment: please see the update of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*emphasized text*You will need to partition the data in collections of equal cardinality:

```
data = [collection of data points]

bins = []
num_bins = 12
data_points_per_bin = len(data) // 12

bins = [data[_ * data_points_per_bin: (_+1)*data_points_per_bin] for _ in range(num_bins)]
```

*This last line is a list comprehension that creates a list of lists (the bins) containing the data points. It iterates over all the data, slices it in groups of equal sizes, and stores it.*

You will probably need to choose a num_bins that is a divisor of the number of data points, and is the closest to the appropriate number, or decide what to do with the data not allocated in a full bin.

**for instance:**

```
data = list(range(48))

num_bins = 12
data_points_per_bin = len(data) // 12

bins = [data[_ * data_points_per_bin: (_+1)*data_points_per_bin] for _ in range(num_bins)]
```

the output is:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 9, 10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23],
 [24, 25, 26, 27],
 [28, 29, 30, 31],
 [32, 33, 34, 35],
 [36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43],
 [44, 45, 46, 47]]
```

Once the data is allocated to each bin, you can plot it.

Comment: thanks, but shouldnt 'bins' be an array of 20 equally spaced elements? e.g. array([  4.50996122e-03,   7.49458897e-03,   1.24544006e-02,
         2.06965446e-02,   3.43932215e-02,   5.71541629e-02,
         9.49779695e-02,   1.57833030e-01,   2.62284668e-01,
         4.35860906e-01,   7.24307412e-01,   1.20364369e+00,
         2.00019784e+00,   3.32390013e+00,   5.52360964e+00,
         9.17905540e+00,   1.52536228e+01,   2.53482520e+01,
         4.21233621e+01,   7.00000000e+01])
In [65]:

Comment: It is going to be difficult to satisfy both the constraint of having bins of equal size, and bins containing the same number of elements. It may be possible, on occasion, by chance, with some datasets, but the general case will be either one, or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the code above and it returns me : [26       0.463769
 32       0.463769
 65       0.927538
 104      0.055652
 128      0.463769
 156      0.927538
 205      0.463769
 348      0.463769
 379      0.890436
 434      0.463769
 457      0.649276
 639      0.463769
 641      0.486957
 673      0.463769
 715      0.125218, instead of a range that I want to cut off

Comment: can you please explain me the last line of your code 'bins = [data[_ * data_points_per_bin: (_+1)*data_points_per_bin] for _ in range(num_bins)]'? many thanks

Comment: See explanation added.